# Perl string split and join

Tags: perl

Here I am trying to first join the array into string and then split it again
but the fourth string "four-five" is also separted. How do I handle this ?I am using
'-' as delimeter

```
$constring = joinstring("One","Two","Three","four-five");
print "$constring\n";

@original=sepstring($constring);
#print "@original\n";

sub joinstring {
   my @names = @_;
   my $size  = @names;
   my $delim = "-";
   my $repdelim = "--";

   my $temp  = $names[0];
   my $temp2;

   for ( $a = 1; $a < $size; $a = $a + 1 ) {
       $temp2 = $names[$a];
       $temp2 =~ s/$delim/$repdelim/;   
       $temp  = "$temp$delim$temp2";
   }
   return "$temp";
}

sub sepstring {
    my $delim1 = "-";
    my $stringpassed = @_[0]; 
    my @values2 = split($delim1, $stringpassed);
    print "@values2"
}
```

Comment: `use warnings;` `use strict;`

Comment: So delimiter by definition should not occur in valid elements => change delimiter, escape it, or limit split element numbers. Btw, `sepstring()` has `1` as implicit return value.

Comment: How should I escape it coz if I escape it the escape sequence can alsoe be part of the string ..?

Comment: why `-` as delimiter of choice in the first place?

Comment: My requirement is that it should be robut enough to handle any input strings of array.. '-' is not mandatory. I can use any but the problem will remain even if I use '+' or anything instead of '-'

Comment: `#`, `##`, `###`, etc. is always more robust than `-`

Comment: what if my string contain # inside. How do I handle in that case..?

Comment: join/split on three `#`, not one `#`

Comment: Sorry to bother you more.. But the problem will persist if my input string is "four###five" . Apologies but I am in urgent need of solution

Comment: Why not use the NULL character?

Answer (score 4):

First, note that your encoding is inherently ambiguous: `"foo---bar"` might decode to either `"foo-", "bar"` or `"foo", "-bar"`, or possibly (if empty elements are allowed) even to `"foo", "", "bar"`.  Thus, what you really need is a better encoding.

A common solution is to choose some character *other* than your delimiter (`-`) as an escape sequence introducer.  For example, Perl itself uses the backslash (`\`) as an escape character in string literals.

Of course, this then means that you need to escape *both* your delimiter *and* the escape character itself.
For example, let's keep `-` as the delimiter, and let's pick `+` as the escape character.

We *could* decide to, say, encode `-` as `+-` and a literal `+` as `++`, but this turns out to be kind of tricky to parse using regexps, since, in order to decide whether or not a `-` character is actually escaped or not, you'd need to check if the number of `+` signs preceding it is odd or even.

It turns out to be much easier if the characters being escaped can never appear inside the escape sequences.  So let's, for example, decide to encode a literal `-` as `+0` and a literal `+` as `+1`.  The encoding and decoding routines would then look something like this:

```
sub join_strings {
    my @strings = @_;
    s/\+/\+1/g, s/\-/+0/g for @strings;
    return join "-", @strings;
}

sub split_string ($) {
    my @strings = split /\-/, shift;
    s/\+0/\-/g, s/\+1/+/g for @strings;
    return @strings;
}
```

(Note: The backslash in `s/\+` is needed because `+` is a regexp metacharacter.  Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting also seems to get confused by the sequence `/-/`, so I added some extra backslashes to keep it happy; those are not strictly needed.)

It's important the the escape character `+` be encoded first and decoded last, otherwise it would interfere with the other en/decoding steps.

Note that the `split_string` function accepts any input string, even if it could never be produced by `join_strings`.  If you want, you can check whether the input contains any unescaped `+` characters with:

```
die "Invalid joined string \"$string\"" if $string =~ /\+(?![01])/;
```

Comment: This is well done and makes much sense.  Have removed my solution since yours is so much more straight forward and elegant.  I appreciate learning from your answer...